# How to make this app multi-select?

Tags: angularjs, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I want below angularjs code like this [example here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple). **","** should be added after every color i select. Like this **red,white,black**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Select a car:</p>

<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x.model for x in cars">
</select>

<h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.model}}</h1>
<p>Its color is: {{selectedCar.color}}</p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = [
        {model : "Ford Mustang", color : "red"},
        {model : "Fiat 500", color : "white"},
        {model : "Volvo XC90", color : "black"}
    ];
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selectbox is for 'one select'

use checkbox

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p>Select a car:</p>

    <span ng-repeat="x in cars">
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='x.checked'/>{{x.color}}
    </span>

    <h1>You selected: {{checkedModels()}}</h1>
    <p>Its color is: {{checkedColors()}}</p>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope , $filter) {
        $scope.cars = [
            {model : "Ford Mustang", color : "red"},
            {model : "Fiat 500", color : "white"},
            {model : "Volvo XC90", color : "black"}
        ];

        $scope.checkedColors = function(){
       var checkedArr = $filter('filter')($scope.cars, {checked : true});
       var text = '';
       for(var i = 0 ; i < checkedArr.length ; i++) {
if(text.length != 0){text += ','}
text += checkedArr[i].color;
}
return text;
}

$scope.checkedModels = function(){
       var checkedArr = $filter('filter')($scope.cars, {checked : true});
       var text = '';
       for(var i = 0 ; i < checkedArr.length ; i++) {
if(text.length != 0){text += ','}
text += checkedArr[i].model;
}
return text;
}


    });
    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a multi select dropdown like below.

```
<select multiple="true" ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x.model for x in cars"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p>Select a car:</p>

    <span ng-repeat="x in cars">
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='x.checked'/>{{x.color}}
    </span>

    <h1>You selected: {{checkedModels()}}</h1>
    <p>Its color is: {{checkedColors()}}</p>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope , $filter) {
        $scope.cars = [
            {model : "Ford Mustang", color : "red"},
            {model : "Fiat 500", color : "white"},
            {model : "Volvo XC90", color : "black"}
        ];

        $scope.checkedColors = function(){
       var checkedArr = $filter('filter')($scope.cars, {checked : true});
       var text = '';
       for(var i = 0 ; i < checkedArr.length ; i++) {
if(text.length != 0){text += ','}
text += checkedArr[i].color;
}
return text;
}

$scope.checkedModels = function(){
       var checkedArr = $filter('filter')($scope.cars, {checked : true});
       var text = '';
       for(var i = 0 ; i < checkedArr.length ; i++) {
if(text.length != 0){text += ','}
text += checkedArr[i].model;
}
return text;
}


    });
    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/angular">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div class="demo-section k-content" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <h4>Select product</h4>
        <select kendo-multi-select k-options="selectOptions" k-ng-model="selectedIds"></select>
        <p ng-show="selectedIds.length" style="padding-top: 1em;">Selected: {{ selectedIds }}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
    .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.selectOptions = {
            placeholder: "Select products...",
            dataTextField: "ProductName",
            dataValueField: "ProductID",
            valuePrimitive: true,
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        $scope.selectedIds = [ 4, 7 ];
      })
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

**this is exactly what i want**